# Coefficients of the polynomials generated by $f_0=x,\ f_{i+1}=f_i\pm\dfrac1{f_i}$.

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, continued-fractions, golden-ratio

Let

$f_0=x,\ f_{i+1}=f_i\pm\dfrac1{f_i}$

for $i\geq0$, i.e., $f_i=\dfrac{\sqrt{f_{i+1}^2\mp4}+f_{i+1}}2$

I have observed that

$f_1=\dfrac{x^2\pm1}x$

$f_2=\dfrac{x^4\pm3x^2+1}{x(x^2\pm1)}$

$f_3=\dfrac{x^8\pm7x^6+13x^4\pm7x^2+1}{x(x^6\pm4x^4+4x^2\pm1)}$

$f_4=\dfrac{x^{16}\pm15x^{14}+83x^{12}\pm220x^{10}+303x^8\pm220x^6+83x^4\pm15x^2+1}{x(x^{14}\pm11x^{12}+45x^{10}\pm88x^8+88x^6\pm45x^4+11x^2\pm1)}$,

and that in the positive case each denominator is the product of all previous numerators.

How can I determine the coefficients?

Edit: Note that all $\pm$ and $\mp$ here are considered to be a single instance, meaning that all $\pm$ are the opposite of all $\mp$, transcendent of the index $i$.

[Sloane's A147990](http://oeis.org/A147990) appears to provide the coefficients for the numerators in the (negative) case when $\pm$ is $-$, so the absolute values should give the coefficients in the positive case. I think I might be able to establish a formula by crawling around oeis for a bit.

Edit: Oops, I didn't realize that the sequence [A147985](http://oeis.org/A147985) that A147990 links to is precisely the sequence I'm looking for.

To be honest, I'm not certain how to define the coefficients based on what's given there.

And then the denominators appear to be given by [A147986](http://oeis.org/A147986), which, as I said, appear to be the product of all previous numerators (in the positive case) as well.

Comment: By 'the numerator' and 'the denominator' I assume you mean the minimal form (where any common polynomial factor have been cancelled)?

Comment: @Winther Maybe? I'm referring to the coefficients in the numerators and denominators of the equations as presented.

Comment: For example if $f_n = \frac{x^2-2x+1}{x-1}$ then this is also equal to $f_n = \frac{x-1}{1}$ so the result for the coefficients will be different.

Comment: @Winther I don't know of any common polynomial factors between numerator and denominator.

Comment: @Winther I believe the latter two sequences mentioned were defined precisely for the sequence I've described. In the formula section, both contain the quote, "The basic idea is to iterate the reciprocation-difference mapping $x/y\to x/y-y/x$." My ideal answer to this question is a formula for the values of each of these sequences, whether as presented in oeis or as in the positive case; the sign is easy enough to replicate

Comment: It is perhaps easier to understand if you introduce a factor $2$ into the  iteration : Assume $f_0 = \frac pq = [p,q] $ then $f_k \to f_{k+1}$ is in your versions equivalent  $T: [p,q] \to [p^2-q^2,  p q ] $. But if you use $U: [p,q] \to [p^2-q^2,  2 p q ] $ instead then we have the formula for the doubling of an angle and numerator $p_k$ and denominator $q_k$ behave like $\cos()$ and $\sin()$ which are the mutual derivatives of each other (except a sign-shift). Also the coefficients are then simply binomial-coefficients. But I do not yet see a further improvement so far...

Comment: Also I've seen, that the iteration is equivalent $T: x \to \sinh(\log(x)) $ and for instance for x=0.5 gives some infinite dance around the origin with slowly increasing intermediate maxima and minima of absolute values.